# How to render a react-router Link component from text?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Here's my situation:

This is a Single Page App that is using `react-router-dom` to perform **client-side routing.**

I have a `AddBlogPostPage` where the **admin** will create `blogPosts`.

- This page has lots of inputs and textareas to build the `blogPost` paragraphs and images.
- Inside a `textarea` input, the admin will **enter a paragraph text that will be rendered inside a `<p>` tag** using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` when the `blogPost` is displayed.
- **But sometimes is necessary to add links to other pages of the App and I'm doing the following:**
- The admin enters in the `textarea`:

  - For example: the text pattern `[products](/products)`
  - And this gets replaced and rendered as `<a href="/products">products</a>`

But when I click on the `<a>` the App **refreshes other than switch routes with `react-router-dom`.** That is **because I'm using an `<a>` tag instead of a `Link` component** that comes built-in with `react-router-dom`.

But since I'm rendering my paragraphs with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, how can I display the React component `Link` instead of an html tag `<a>` in this situation?

From my research so far, this does not seem to be possible. Is there any other way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm quite sure this isn't the the most efficient way of doing it, nor is it really reuseable. But here is, at least, a starting point.

You're storing that textarea information in state, I assume. When rendering it FROM state, use

```
const firstText = this.state.userText.split('[products]');
```

to get everything before your tag, then

```
const lastText = firstText[1].split('[/products]');
```

to get everything after your link. Your render will look something like:

```
<p>
    {firstText[0]}
    <Link to="/products">{lastText[0]}</Link>
    {lastText[1]}
</p>
```

For an actual use case, you'll want to store that in state, keep track of what & where all of your tags are, and throw everything into an array in a separate state entry so you can map the output appropriately. This would undoubtedly be a method instead of a series of variable declarations. And I'm sure it's not terribly efficient. But it's not impossible!

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks! I'm currently trying to build something like that. That's the only way I've thought about doing it so far. It should work, I guess.

Comment: Also, if you use this starting point to grow additional code, make sure you're checking to make sure arrays like lastText (or whatever) exist before referencing their index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this I write for that..

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
export const addLinkToText = (text) => {
        const sptx= text.split('|');
        const newTxt=sptx.map((txt,indx) => {
            const sptx2= txt.split(':');
            if(sptx2.length>1){
                return <Link key={`lk${indx}`} to={sptx2[1]}>{sptx2[0]}</Link>
            }
            return sptx2[0];
        });
        return newTxt;
}
```

And then parse text like this:

```
<div>{addLinkToText("some text |text for link:/path_of_url| more text.")}</div>
```